# Flutter: How to fetch all the data from Firebase Firestore?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a collection of 'users' and I am trying to fetch all the documents and render them in a Flutter app. But whenever I run the app, it shows a casting error and I cannot understand what is wrong in the code.

Here is the function to fetch all the users.

```
  Stream<List<AddUserRequestModel>> getAllUsers() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots().map(
        (snapshot) => snapshot.docs
            .map((doc) => AddUserRequestModel.fromJson(doc.data()))
            .toList() as List<AddUserRequestModel>);
  }
```

And i am trying to render the documents like so :

```
 body: StreamBuilder<List<AddUserRequestModel>>(
        stream: getAllUsers(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final List<AddUserRequestModel> users =
                snapshot.data as List<AddUserRequestModel>;
            return ListView(
                children: users.map((user) {
              return ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(child: Text('${user.age}')),
                title: Text(user.name!),
                subtitle: Text(user.city!),
              );
            }).toList());
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            print(snapshot.error);
            return const Center(child: Text('Something went wrong.'));
          } else {
            return const LoadingUIComponent(message: 'Loading Users...');
          }
        },
      ),
```

This is the model class that I am using :

```
class AddUserRequestModel {
  String? id;
  String? name;
  int? age;
  String? city;

  AddUserRequestModel({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.age,
    this.city,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {
      'id': id?.trim(),
      'name': name?.trim(),
      'age': age,
      'city': city?.trim(),
    };
    map.removeWhere((key, value) => value == null);
    return map;
  }

  static fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => AddUserRequestModel(
        id: json['id'],
        name: json['name'],
        age: json['age'],
        city: json['city'],
      );
}
```

This is the error that I am getting :

> type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast

Can someone explain what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you have casted it twice, both in the `getAllUsers()` and `StreamBuilder`. And you cannot directly cast `List` the way you have done, compiler needs a bit more clarity as how to cast elements.

Try using the following code:

```
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getAllUsers() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots()
  }
```

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: getAllUsers(), 
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Text('Something went wrong');
            }
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Text("Loading");
            }
            return ListView(
                children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
              AddUserRequestModel data = AddUserRequestModel.fromJson(document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>);
              // AddUserRequestModel data = AddUserRequestModel.fromJson(document.data()!);
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(data.name),
              );
            }).toList());
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: It shows the folowing error: ```type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'AddUserRequestModel' in type cast``` in the line where you have used ``` AddUserRequestModel data = document.data()! ;```

Comment: @Arijeet Sorry my bad, i forgot to use the `fromJson` method. Please try with the updated code, if this doesn't work , try with the commented one. and let me know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the update. You literally saved me. :)

Answer (score 2):

The error is probably coming from *getAllUsers()* method.

your function:

```
 Stream<List<AddUserRequestModel>> getAllUsers() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots().map(
        (snapshot) => snapshot.docs
            .map((doc) => AddUserRequestModel.fromJson(doc.data()))
            .toList() as List<AddUserRequestModel>);
  }
```

In this the *toList()* method in dart returns a `List<dynamic>`, but you casted it to `List<AddUserRequestModel>`. That can be the cause of error.

Workarounds:

1. remove the casting done in the method *getAllUsers()*. The code would work fine.
2. If you want to cast do: `.toList().cast<AddUserRequestModel>() as List<AddUserRequestModel>` .
3. You can also specify the return type on the map method. Specify the type like this:

edited code:

```
  Stream<List<AddUserRequestModel>> getAllUsers() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots().map(
        (snapshot) => snapshot.docs
            .map<AddUserRequestModel>((doc) => AddUserRequestModel.fromJson(doc.data()))
            .toList());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a type to your map function, so you don't get a `List<dynamic>`

```
Stream<List<AddUserRequestModel>> getAllUsers() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots().map<AddUserRequestModel>(
        (snapshot) => snapshot.docs
            .map((doc) => AddUserRequestModel.fromJson(doc.data()))
            .toList());
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't work. This whole function shows a casting error.

Comment: Show the casting error